# Ubuntu configuration for dialup

Tags: internet, configure, ppp

I need to configure dialup on my computer because it is the only internet I have access to at school. I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to have done anything.

pppconfig (pon/poff)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `pon/poff'

I'm not sure what else to put down but I will answer any questions to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
adduser $USER dip
adduser $USER dialout
pppconfig
```

You will be on the main menu ---- Choose ---- Create Create a connection.

Leave the name as ---- provider ---- hit Ok.

Select ---- Dynamic Use dynamic DNS ---- hit Ok.

Select ---- PAP Peer Authentication Protocol ---- hit Ok.

Enter ---- your user name for the ISP ---- hit Ok.

Enter ---- your password for the ISP ---- hit Ok.

Leave the speed at ---- 115200 as recommended ---- hit Ok.

Choose ---- Tone or Pulse dialing ---- hit Ok.

Enter ---- the phone number to your ISP (do not use any dashes) ---- hit Ok.

You can try to have your modem detected automatically.

If the modem wasn't detected, it will ask you for the port your modem is on.

Enter ---- the device name for your modem ---- hit Ok.

Choose ---- Finished Write files and return to main menu.

Choose ---- Quit Exit this utility.

Exit the terminal window, type:

```
  exit
  exit
```

Connecting to the ISP:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
   pon
```

Disconnecting to the ISP:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
   poff
```

Comment: I think I will need to get the info once I get back to school. I apologize but this might take a while as I get an internet connection. I do know of a few places I can go for wireless.

Comment: Last time I tried configuring dialup I started running into some trouble with my modem. I don't think the driver was installed.